# Was slf4j affected with vulnerability issue in log4j

Tags: java, security, logging, log4j, slf4j

I have implemented a POC and have used slf4j for logging. The zero day vulnerability issue in log4j, did that also impact slf4j logs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depends on the underlying implementation of SLF4J.
log4j 1.x is safe with respect to CVE-2021-44228. Thus, if your SLF4J provider/binding is slf4j-log4j12.jar, you are safe regarding CVE-2021-44228.

If you are using log4j-over-slf4j.jar in conjunction with the SLF4J API, you are safe unless the underlying implementation is log4j 2.x.

Check this - http://slf4j.org/log4shell.html

Comment: how to know underlying implementation version ?

Comment: please tell how to know the underlying implementation ?

Comment: You need to use some other logging library like Logback or Log4j to get your app logging. Only using slf4j will not generate logs. So you will add log4j or any other implementation of SLF4j in your pom file. The thing to make sure is not to use vulnerable Log4j versions.

Comment: @tryingToLearn If you are using maven try mvn dependency:tree | grep log4j or check pom.xml

Comment: @2sb In the dependency tree, i didn't find any log4j but found logback. Is this possible sl4j will not use log4j at all?

Comment: @tryingToLearn True,  Slf4j natively use logback and congratulations your application is safe :)

Comment: is slf4j from lombok vulnerable ? lombok plugin version being used is 6.0.0-m2

Answer (score 5):

It depends. Slf4j is just an api, that can be using behind any of its implementions, being log4j just one. Check which one is using on the back, and if this is log4j and between versions 2.0.0 and 2.15.0 (2.15.0 is the one with the fix, versions 1.x are not affected) you should update it (if it is exposed to users directly or indirectly)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apache](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html), "only the log4j-core JAR file is impacted by this vulnerability. Applications using only the log4j-api JAR file without the log4j-core JAR file are not impacted by this vulnerability.
Also Apache Log4j is the only Logging Services subproject affected by this vulnerability. Other projects like Log4net and Log4cxx are not impacted by this."

So you should be safe, as long as you do not use log4j-core package.

Answer (score 0):

[,1.7.26),[1.8.0-alpha0,1.8.0-beta2) has Vulnerabilities. Please follow the link https://snyk.io/vuln/maven:org.slf4j:slf4j-ext